# Need square brackets at the start/end of the spring boot logging console

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I have a special requirement where I need to have square brackets at the start and end of the spring boot application logs. i.e.
[
  spring boot application starting logs start here and print everything for all the ongoing logs further from here.
]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can override the logging pattern in application.properties:

```
logging.pattern.console=[%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}]
```

Read more about custom logging configuration in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration

Comment: Thanks Simon. Actually this will print [log event data] on each line. I want to have only one time starting and ending square brackets and in between them all the ongoing logs should be printed.

Comment: That's not possible. Logging is line based